# selected items in one alert

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Hello everyone
I am new to flex so please excuse if it is noob question.
I have 2 comboboxes which are dependent (country and state) and one submit button.
Now what i want is after user submits the form it should display one alert box which should be 
like

```
selected country is "selected item"
selected state is"selected item"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample in its simple form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("Selected country is "+'"'+cm1.selectedItem+'"\n'+"Selected state is "+'"'+cm2.selectedItem+'"');
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ComboBox id="cm1" width="150" dataProvider="['a1','b1','c1']"/>
    <mx:ComboBox id="cm2" width="150" dataProvider="['a1a','b1b','c1c']"/>
    <mx:Button label="Submit" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

- For getting each combobox selected item as text use `selectedItem.label`. [see here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_5.html).
- For popping alerts use `Alert.show`. [see here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_19.html).
- For string building use `+` operator.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/ComboBoxEvent.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >
   <mx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
         import mx.controls.Alert;
      ]]>
   </mx:Script>

   <mx:ComboBox id="mycb"> 
      <mx:ArrayCollection>
         <mx:Object label="AL" data="Montgomery"/>
         <mx:Object label="AK" data="Juneau"/>
         <mx:Object label="AR" data="Little Rock"/>
      </mx:ArrayCollection>
   </mx:ComboBox>
     <mx:ComboBox id="mycb2"> 
      <mx:ArrayCollection>
         <mx:Object label="US" data="United States"/>
         <mx:Object label="MX" data="Mexico"/>
         <mx:Object label="IR" data="Ireland"/>
      </mx:ArrayCollection>
   </mx:ComboBox>
   <mx:Button id="button1" label="Submit" click="Alert.show('Submit Successful!  State: '+{mycb.selectedItem}+' Country:'+{mycb2.selectedItem}, 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);"/>
" width="100"/>
</mx:Application>
```